# What could be causing my water to turn brown?

Tags: plumbing, water

On a lot with two houses (detached from each other), one of them is having a problem where the water at all the fixtures is brown. Oddly, the other house *does not* have this problem. This is weird because there is only one water main coming into the house with brown water. I know the main goes into the house with brown water, and that the house with clear water is fed straight from the main trunk. Other parts of that trunk feed the house with brown water as well.

This is confusing me because the house with brown water has it at all the fixtures, suggesting it's coming from the main, but that same main also feeds the house with clear water.

Here is a plumbing diagram:

[image: plumbing diagram]

Comment: Is it well water or aqueduct water? Does the clean water house have a filtre fitted?

Comment: City supplied. No filters.

Comment: If only hot water is brown the issue is in the boiler.

Comment: Both hot and cold. Also, the issue appeared to have resolved itself, but I'd still like to determine the cause

Comment: Maybe a work on the aqueduct done when one house was using water and not the other: dirt went only in the home that was using water, then come clean water that kept flowing to the other house whose pipes were full of 'old' clean water because wasn't using water at the time dirt come, other house had to 'flush' all the pipes that were filled with dirty water so got 'dirt' for some time.

Comment: It could be... Honestly, I really don't know what happened, but it may be a good case for a whole house sediment filter